# How to Push Objects into Array - Polymer 2.x

Tags: arrays, push, polymer-2.x

I am trying to push items to an array in Polymer. `this.request` is in a `dom-repeat` template and it displays correctly in the DOM. However, when I log `this.request` it shows that the last entry overwrote all previous entries.

For example, if I push `1,2,3,4` as descriptions, the `dom-repeat` will be accurate, but when I log `this.request` it shows `4,4,4,4`.

```
<ul id="products">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[request]]" restamp="true">
    <li>
      <p>[[item.description]]</p>
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

...

```
request: {
  type: Object,  
  value: []
},

productData: {
  type:Object,
  value: {}  
}
```

...

```
addItemToList() {
  this.push('request', this.productData);
}
```

Trying to workaround with `this.set` produces no DOM update, and array indices still get overwritten.

```
addItemToList() {
  let i = 'request.' + this.request.length;
  this.set(i, this.productData)
}
```

**The problem seems be arising from pushing objects instead of strings, can objects be pushed as array indices?**

What method can be used to keep these in sync?

Comment: below is solving the issue? I just curious, whether below demo is solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can push the object into an array as you described. I could not understood how you produce the `productData`, but I tried to illustrate an examples below:

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/xBmPaE?editors=1011)

```
addItemToList() {
  this.productData = {description:this.request.length}
  this.push('request', this.productData);
    console.log(this.request)  
}
```

You can see more detailed code at demo link.